# ARM Mini Mobile Device Development

Tags: pcb, arm, device, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ARM Processor on a PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31288/arm-processor-on-a-pcb)

I'm trying to build a mini device with 3 buttons (that will each preform a task) and it will have an ARM Processor, no screen or form of display, and a rechargeable battery (or some form of battery like lithium ion or AA). I also want it to have an OS (bootloader, kernel), developed by myself, that will detect the 3 buttons and when one of the buttons is pressed it will call a function in the OS.

1. How do I start this? I have several  [buttons](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/97), PCBs, and a soldering gun. Where and how do I get an ARM Processor to solder onto a PCB?
2. What type of ARM Processor would I use for this kind of a project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're way over your head.  Even soldering a modern ARM processor is not a trivial task.

Start with a [Launchpad](http://ti.com/launchpad).

The Launchpad has enough hardware for what you want to do, and it is much less complex than the ARM.  The MSP430 uses a flat address space, Von Neumann architecture, which will allow you to develop your operating system without headaches from paging and banking.

If you must use ARM, choose a development board (such as the ones from olimex.com) to get started.  Or use a Raspberry Pi if you can get one.

Comment: paging and segments are headaches for you? :S

Comment: They're extra helping of accidental complexity for the beginning microcontroller programmer.

Comment: @markrages couldn't soldering and ARM Processor be as easy as...<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhhLyxkTVQI">this</a>?

Comment: Sure.  (If you don't have experience soldering TQFP, I suggest you learn with cheap / scrap boards.)  But soldering will be the easiest part of this project.