# ARM processor on a PCB

Tags: pcb, soldering, arm

I've been working on a PCB that will hold a LED,  3 buttons, an ARM7 processor, a bluesmirf receiver and a voltage source (eg. battery). Something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXqA6C4Gckg&feature=BFa&list=PL3DF8FCA6826A7F35) , but with more components.

1. How could I program the ARM processor (I want to put a RTOS on it)?. Once it's [placed on the PCB](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhhLyxkTVQI&feature=BFa&list=PL3DF8FCA6826A7F35) will I be able to program it)?
2. I want to buy the processor by itself (no development boards). Do I go to www.arm.com for that or is there somewhere better?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't solder it as badly as the guy in the video.

Comment: Yeah, and start by not doing PCBs like that. One of the holes (in 0:46) doesn't even have copper around it.

Comment: Which controller are you using?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? (== why do you specifically want to use an ARM7 and an RTOS)?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I need some sort of an operating system that will detect the 3 buttons (and determine if they are on or off and when the button is pressed send an action to the operating system), turn the light on and off (not when the button is pressed but on other actions determined by the operating system), determine the amount of power in a battery and on boot up check for the 3 buttons. I heard that ARM7 would be good for something like this.

Comment: "I need some sort of an operating system that will detect the 3 buttons" — this is not the job of an operating system. It might help you by providing peripheral drivers (but a manufacturer's peripheral support library will do that too) and by providing queues and tasks so you can post events from an ISR in a queue and handle them in tasks (this is an overkill for such a trivial problem as yours). You will need to program actual button, LED and serial data handling yourself, OS or not. This is considered application logic in microcontrollers.

Comment: FreeRTOS.org actually offers an ARM CPU setup. You may want to try their kit. http://shop.freertos.org/, I am anxiously waiting for mine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

0 . Strictly speaking, ARM7 is not a processor, it's a microcontroller. (You'd have a hard time finding a *processor* that doesn't require external RAM and flash memory for program storage.)

0.5. You seem to assume that you'll be able to install a RTOS on it and launch applications like it were a PC. This is not going to be the case. (It's not entirely impossible but it's hardly worth the trouble.) This is a *microcontroller*, it runs firmware from flash. You recompile the firmware and reprogram the chip using e.g. JTAG every time you make a change. An RTOS in this context is just a threading library, perhaps with standartized peripheral drivers (not always).

1 . You will need to use JTAG (recommended) or a custom bootloader designed by a specific chip manufacturer. SWD is not supported on ARM7TDMI to the best of my knowledge. Both cheap opensource and expensive commercial JTAG tools are available for ARM including ARM7TDMI. JTAG offers remote debugging support, not just programming.

2 . What ARM makes is cores, i.e. circuit descriptions that actual silicon vendors implement in actual ICs (while adding a whole lot of custom peripherals). You should familiarize yourself with actual products based on your ARM core that are available. There are many of them, and they are quite different, both in core features and peripherals. ARM itself doesn't sell any chips. Atmel, ST and many others do. It's too early to think about a PCB until you do this.

2.5. Any ARM microcontroller, whether an ARM7 or a Cortex-M (see below), consists of two large parts: the core (supplied and documented by ARM) and peripherals (designed and documented by the chip manufacturer). You will need to study at least two reference manuals (and probably also a datasheet) for any chip to implement in your device. This will be at least a 2,000-page required reading that you don't seem to have started yet.

3 . ARM7 is obsolete and largely replaced by Cortex-M. ARM7TDMI is an implementation of the ARMv4 architecture while Cortex-M cores conform to the newer ARMv7-M (with certain variations) or to ARMv6 (Cortex-M0). ARM7TDMI microcontrollers are still being produced of course but it makes little sense to use them in new designs. Again, Cortex-M MCUs are produced by ST, TI, Atmel, Energy Micro and many others.

Comment: O.k. So I have read what you have said and it is an eye opener. BAsed on what you have said, I believe that you have experience with ARM _microcontrollers_. I need this device to be supported by an operating system (not necessarily an RTOS but it has to detect 3 buttons and an LED of which it will control) and based on your answer and the needs listed in the question what kind of ARM microcontroller should I get and who should I get it from?

Comment: The only kind of OS you can find on a microcontroller is a RTOS. Your needs are pretty trivial, any MCU with a UART (your bluetooth module appears to use a serial interface) would do (and I'm not aware of any ARM MCU out there that wouldn't have UARTs). Based on the user interface you're describing (3 buttons and a LED) the data rate isn't going to be high at all either. You can use pretty much anything. Of course if you do need an RTOS (why?) the chip will need to have enough RAM, but it's still not a lot. You can use STM32F1 (STM32VLDiscovery or an Olimex board) among many other choices.

Comment: @Coder404 - you keep insisting on an operating system when you mention the buttons. But millions of microcontroller applications handle buttons and LEDs without RTOS, which adds several levels of complexity, probably without good reason.

Comment: @stevenvh Well I have recently decided to add a camera to the device so an os of some type is now needed

Comment: @Coder404 No it's not.  Do you have any idea what the operating systems for microcontrollers of this size actually do?  Typically there's no filesystems, no drivers, and no TCP/IP stacks.  Normally you get a task switcher, memory management and inter-process communication.  That's it.  Unless you pay thousands of dollars for a license for a professional OS you won't get anything that makes your life as easy as you want it to be.

Comment: @AngryEE I heard that from a friend. What kind of microcontroller should I use?

Comment: Any microcontroller will work. Use the one you're familiar with.  If you're not familiar with one you have to start from the bottom and work up.  You can't just jump right in at this level (despite its simplicity).  You don't have any of the necessary background knowledge.

Answer (score 10):

It seems like you want to use a soviet era rocket launcher to kill a fly. Your task is *very* simple, but you talking about using a fairly powerful microcontroller and an operating system to control it.

The ARM7 is reasonably powerful 32-bit MCU with hardware multiplier. It typically has lots of input / output pins. Here's a picture of one:

[image: ARM7]

Look at all that cool stuff it's doing. It's running a screen, with loads of colours. I can't tell, but I bet it's animating that in real time too. This chip probably has more computing power than my first PC (and I used to play Wing Commander on that).

I'm not sure exactly how much computing power you want in your application, but from the sound of it: *one* LED, three buttons, and a UART for Bluetooth, I suspect it isn't much.

---

My suggestion would be to select a much simpler MCU. Perhaps an 8 or 16 pin device. Something like a [PIC16F1823](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41413B.pdf). Or something with a little more power, a [PIC18F1220](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39605F.pdf) perhaps:

[image: PIC18F1220]

They can both be programmed in C, and have plenty of functionality, including a UART.

Comment: `to use a soviet era rocket launcher to kill a fly` great figuration :)

Comment: A person that wants to kill one fly should not be helped, flys eat and help decompose dead biomass.  If there's a swarm, that's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

1. Place a JTAG or a SWD header on a PCB and you'll be able to program the chip in circuit. You'll need a compatible JTAG programmer.
2. ARM does not sell chips, they sell (or rather licence) cores (designs). It's hard to recommend a better place without knowing your location, but try distributors such as Digikey, Farnell or RS. There will be a ton of arm chips. If you don't know which one you want, try looking at STM32 line from ST or LPC line from NXP.

Comment: I am in New York so which should I use?

Comment: You should probably go to Digikey then, but you can also try Newark and Mouser.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't chosen your ARM yet, you can get chips from Farnell , RS, Digikey, Mouser etc. ARM doesn't make chips, they only design the proccesor core.
LPC2100 is a ARM7 serie from NXP. I don't know from ST, but I do know a couple of other manufacturers make ARM chips.

Most ARM chips come in TQFP, QFN or BGA. Avoid QFN and especially BGA, not fun soldering time. 
Most TQFP chips are 0.5mm, which is pretty small. However, the video you have shown with solderpaste(???) and hot air(???) on a TQFP may be a little bit overkill. It's possible with some flux, small tin (<0.5mm), solder wick and a reasonable iron.
Home etched PCB's are also fine, however I do believe 0.5mm pitch devices are pretty for small for DIY PCB's.

You can program the micro on PCB via JTAG or SWD. I believe JTAG is most common for ARM7. For this you need a ARM compatible JTAG programmer or debugger. Olimex is a 3rd party manufacturer that makes these, but there are also several 'hacks' circulating around a FT2232 chip. 
Alternatively, you can use the serial bootloader. I know NXP has this, I am not sure for the other manufacturers. Olimex has got this on some of their boards, allowing programming (no debugging) of a new HEX file via Flashmagic or LPC2100 bootloader utility. You may be able to use their circuit for it.
I believe it consists of connecting a serial port to one of the UART's, and a certain 'bootloader enable' pin which must be held low during reset.

Note that a RTOS will only help in multitasking on a microcontroller, it will serve little purpose in helping the microcontroller getting a new program.

Answer (score 0):

You will find things much easier if you prototype your application using an LPCXpresso board:

http://ics.nxp.com/lpcxpresso/

When it's working, design your PCB using the same chip and software.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-System_Programming) (see datasheet/application note).
2. You can get an ARM microcontroller from any distributor (mouser, digikey ...). The datasheet of the chosen microcontroller contains information on the ISP layout.